# Chrome not sending Ajax Data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a strange behaviour with jquery's `$.ajax` using Chrome, this is my code:

```
$('.edtBtn').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var $inputs = $('#saveForm'+id+' :input');
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                data: $inputs,
                url: "ajax/save.php?timestamp=<?php echo time();?>",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data === "success"){
                        $('#saved'+id).attr('src', 'images/saved.png');
                    }
                },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown); 
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

When I hit the Button in IE, everything is executed smoothly, in Chrome however, it gives me a "success" as well, but doesn't send the inputs?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `data: $inputs.serialize(),`

Comment: Could you provide us the html code of your form, or put your script in a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not PHP :-)

```
var $inputs
data: $inputs,
```

Try

```
var inputs
data: inputs,
```

Then, you could also try the $.post() function

```
$('.edtBtn').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var inputs = $('#saveForm'+id+' :input');
    $.post("ajax/save.php?timestamp=<?php echo time();?>", {inputs.serialize()},
       function(data){      
                $('#saved'+id).attr('src', 'images/saved.png');
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check the code above?? `var $inputs = $('#saveForm'+id+' :input');` in js you CAN use variable names with $ sign!

Comment: tell it to the developers of jQuery framework or any other framework using $ in it. Anyway, your answer is not related to the OP's problem at all.

Comment: `var input = $('#saveForm'+id+' :input').val();` and what if there are two or more inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a jquery object off to the server.
You should use `.serializeArray()` on the form.

`var arr = $("#saveForm" + id).serializeArray();`

This will give you an array of all the name value pairs contained within the form.
To change it to an object use:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) obj[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
```

Then pass `obj` to the server.

Comment: Well thank you but I can't get this code to work.
In a complete different project I'm using      `$('.saveFeature').click(function(){
  if ($('.saveFeature').attr('rel') == 'Alloc'){
   var $inputs = $('#allocSave').serialize(); 
   $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: $inputs,
    url: "ajax/or_cfg_enterroomnumber.php?timestamp="+jstime+"<?php echo time();?>",
    success: function(data) {
     sendDialog(data);
    }
   });
   
  return false;
  }
});`

and it works like a charm in all browsers?!?!? (Sorry formatting is not my best... Still reading how to...)

Comment: The reason it's working is because you're using `.serialize()`. You're not using `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()` in the OP. Instead, you're sending a jquery object to the server!